# Strange wire when connecting Wifi Relay to electrical heater

Tags: wiring, uk, radiator

I am looking to install a WiFi relay for my electric heaters (I'm planning on connecting them up to my smart home system so that they can work on a thermostat)

I was just looking to install the relay but I am confused by how the radiators are wired up

[image]

The wall switch looks like a 2 pole switch, and it has the brown live going into the live input terminal as expected, but into the neutral terminal there is a grey wire. Then the load neutral is connected directly to the input neutral

The grey wire, when the switch is on, connects to a black wire that comes from the flex of the radiator.

Looking at the manual for the radiator, this black wire is a pilot wire. My understanding (I have been doing a lot of reading on them since I was previously planning on just replacing the whole lot!) Is that these pilot wires are only commonly used in France.

[Radiator manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1278866/Atlantic-F18.html?page=8#manual)

I have checked and my other radiators are all wired up the same way. To my knowledge all my radiators are independently controlled and there is no "master" radiator that controls them all.

I have no idea what this extra grey cable is doing or what else it is connected to.

My current plan is to rewire them all so that the neutral wires are connected to the input and load of the switch (im pretty sure this is how they are supposed to be connected anyway?), connect the relay on the live wire between the switch and radiator, and leave the black/grey wires completely disconnected.

Am I missing something really important with this plan? I did consider the possibility that these are 3 phase, but the manual for the radiators state that they are 220/230v. Is there any way to test to confirm that it isn't whilst the breakers are off?

Comment: *"but into the neutral terminal there is a grey wire"*.  Um, why would **a switch** have a neutral wire?  *"2 pole switch"* How can a 2-pole switch have only 3 wires going to it?  Something is wrong with the presumptions.  You have been reading about new installations, perhaps you area assuming the wires currently in your wall match what the smart device instructions call for.  That would be convenient, but does not make it likely.

Comment: There are 4 wires going to the switch labeled on the switch: live, neutral, live load, neutral load. The one you may have missed is the black one from the flex that I mentioned the manual states is a pilot wire. It is also fairly common to also have the neutral wire switched on fused spurs for safety reasons

Comment: Oh, you're right, there is another wire there. Both cables are 3-core.  Neutral is plainly there but not being switched.  Something else is going on with the 2 live wires.  I wonder if the previous installer "did something non-standard" with the 2-pole switch, noting that earth is also not connected, implying the last installer had a very low standard of work.

Comment: 'tis a bit concerning that the ground doesn't seem to be connected to _anything_ at all. I'm sure there's _somewhere_ it should go...

Comment: @FreeMan the radiator is a class 2 appliance so doesn't need to be earthed, and it doesn't actually have any wires to earth it. The face plate is metal though so that should probably be connected